# What is the difference between `pt` and `px` in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm a little confused on the px vs pt conversion in photoshop.  When I change the font size from 12pt to 16px should the size stay the same?  Instead I see the the size of the text decrease when I change from 12pt to 16px.

Answer (score 4):

Points are really more intended as a print measurement. They're still very common to use, but comparing to pixels is going to give you varying results. 1 point is 1/72.27", and your inch measurement in pixels is going to vary depending on the resolution of your document.

Answer (score 4):

Points and pixels aren't the same thing. Point is a print term, and really has no meaning in digital displays, at least not one that you can nail down with any accuracy across platforms and browsers. You are better off using relative sizes. Do not use pixel sizes for type, however, since that can negate the browser's built-in font resizing ability (which is important for visually impaired users).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change your Photoshop ----**Edit------Preferences** and move to **(Units and Rulers)** and set **Pixels for Type**.....

And use Pixels instead of Points